# launching chrome with extension running (python + selenium) how to keep browser open

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am currently trying to launch google chrome with a certain chrome extension using Selenium and Python. The script works partially, google chrome detects and launches with the extension I wish to add though after the browser launches it closes almost instantly (error code: "...selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created"). How do I keep the browser open after chrome launches with the extension? The script does not read anything past the driver launch, "driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:/Webdriver/chromedriver.exe')"

**code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

unpacked_extension_path = '/path/to/unpacked/extension/''

options = Options()

options.add_argument('--load-extension={}'.format(unpacked_extension_path))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:/Webdriver/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('example.com')
```

I have tried adding "chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)" and/or "global driver."Any help would be very appreciated!

**screen-capture:**

https://gyazo.com/52d6d6e6cfa61f5d8660204d773b5d03

Comment: Are the Chrome Browser and Driver versions matching? If they are, then try to close all Chrome browser windows and then try to run the script?

Comment: thank you for the response! the chrome driver is compatible with the browser and the chrome tabs are all closed, no difference.